# Java virtual machine error in runnung pycharm

Tags: pycharm

when in /home/yelesee/pycharm-2018.2/bin i run pycharm.sh with ./pycharm.sh
it sends this errors:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /home/yelesee/pycharm-2018.2/bin/JetbrainsCrack-2.9-release-enc.jar 
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

and my jar file is ok tarketed.
how to fix this?

Comment: were you trying to run pycharm 64bit?

Comment: in /home/yelesee/pycharm-2018.2/bin i run ./pycharm.sh